# Accessing an array not working

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, this seems weird to me!

I have an array with user objects saved in it using the user id as the array key

```
Array (
    [75] => pwUser Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 75
                    [display_name] => Chris Waa
                )
        )

    [1] => pwUser Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [display_name] => Alex Müller
                )
        )

)
```

I now want to access this array with the following code

```
$this->users[$notification['subscribeNotID']]->getAvatar()
```

But I'm receiving an error

> Notice: Undefined index: in NotificationList.class.php on line 217
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAvatar() on a non-object in
>   NotificationList.class.php on line 217

Okay, let's var_dump `$notification['subscribeNotID']`

> string(2) "75"

The key 75 is definitely available in the array!
Curiously, the script works like that

```
$ID = "75"; // var_dump() returns the same as $notification["subscribeNotID"] above
$this->users[$ID]->getAvatar()
```

**Why?**

Comment: any chance $notification['subscribeNotID'] is being treated as INT ?

Comment: Can you show us that class with method getAvatar?

Comment: @Techmonk `$notification['subscribeNotID']` is definitely a string. And even if it would be an integer: `$ID = 75` is also working. `$ID = intval(notification['subscribeNotID'])` not.

Comment: @MarcoD that returns an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'`

Comment: Have you tried to sort array before accessing? (ie. id=75 would be after id=1)

Comment: @Kamil That's a huge class. I doubt that the class is the problem because I access this class many times without any errors. Only in this particular case.

Comment: @Voitcus Why should that change anything? Nvm I tried it, same error.

Comment: Have you tried to dump that directly above `$this->users[$notification['subscribeNotID']]->getAvatar();` line?

Comment: I don't know. Please check if $notification['subscribeNotID']==='75'

Comment: Maybe try to cast that index to integer?

Comment: Why don't you use `intval($notification['subscribeNotID'])`, your `var_dump` shows a string value.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I did that, still the same error.

Comment: Can you print result of this? `$notification["subscribeNotID"]==="75"`